# How to select the location of submatrices to have specific property in the output of multiplication

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix

I want to set the locations of two submatrices `W22` and `W21` taken from Hadamard matrix, with respect to `W22` keeps being unitary and matrix `T` has non-zeros values in the first columns only (Regardless the number of columns that are non-zeros), `T` is sparse matrix. How to do that in Matlab?

For example this is the matlab code:

```
N = 16;       %size of the matrix 
P = N/4;      % size of the submatrix must be unitary
W = hadamard(N);  %Hadamard matrix 

W21 = W(end- P +1:end, 1:end- P);     %Initial submatrix 
W22 = W(end- P +1:end,end- P +1:end);  %the other submatrix
T = inv(W22)*W21;
```

I really don’t know how to start that process, I tried the following way:

```
s = rand(size(T,2),1);    % set a random vector with first values to be zeros to be optimized
s(1: P) = 0;    
T2 = sum(abs(T*s));
```

So, I need to keep the submatrix `W22` unitary and optimize the `T2`, but I couldn’t know how to do that process. Please, any help.

Comment: It hard to be sure if I understood correctly the properties you expect, could you give a piece of code that checks if a given matrix has the property you want?

Comment: @Bob this is the issue I face, I couldn't write that code, but what i want is the matrix 'W22' is unitary, means that $W22 \times W22'$ give a diagonal matrix, and the second condition the matrix 'T' has non-zeros values only in first columns, for example the first 8 columns are any values which might be different from zeros while the other columns are  zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is
$W_{2,2} W_{2,2}^T = I$

$T = W_{2,2}^{-1} W_{2,1}$

If $T$ has non-zero elements only in the first collumn it means that $T = \begin{bmatrix} \textbf C & \textbf 0_{P \times (P-r)}\end{bmatrix}$ where $\textbf C$ is a $P \times r$ matrix.

For any $T$, it is straightforward to compute $W_{2,1} = W_{2,2} T$.
One property of $W_{2,1}$ is that it also will have non-zero elements only in the first column, and is given by $W_{2,1}  = \begin{bmatrix} W_{2,2}\, \textbf C &  \textbf 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, but it's not necessary that $c$ is single columns matrix, it could be more than one one column. Second, $W_{2,2}$ and $W_{2,1}$ are taken from the Hadamard matrix so I need to optimize the optimal submatrices that achieve those conditions.

Comment: sorry, I read "first column" where you wrote "first column**s**" but that doesn't change the procedure. There is nothing to optimize, if the Hadamard matrices are fixed, and we have a closed solution to your problem, the only variables you have to choose are the elements of $\mathbf c$